# Asp.net mvc 5 count and group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried but cannot do well.will suggest me, how to count the number of employee from database table group by department where joining date after 2014.asp.net mvc 5
regards
arun

Comment: Dude, this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read FAQ -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour, How to Ask - > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and Help Centre http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query:

```
   Select DepartmentID, COUNT(1) 
   From Employees
   Where DepartmentJoinDate > '1/1/2014'
   Group By DepartmentID
```